# Background minimizes when minimizing window

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML/CSS.

I am building a simple webpage, but whenever I minimize the window, the background color minimizes with it. So when I scroll to the right, the background is blank.

HTML:

```css
    #body{
     width:100%;
     overflow:scroll;
     /*overflow-x:scroll;*/
     /*position:relative;*/
    }

    .container {
     padding:20px 70px;
     width:1000px;
     position:absolute;
    }

    div.top {
     background-color: #6495ed;
     width:100%;
     height:400px;
     margin:0;
    }

    div.top_text {
     padding:25px;
     margin:35px;
     float:left;
     display:inline-block;
     width:550px;
    }

    div.top_form {
     border : 2px solid;
     border-radius:20px;
     padding:15px;
     /*float:left;*/
     display:inline-block;
     width:auto;
     background-color:#00edca;
    }
```

```html
 <body id="body">
  <div class="top" align="center">
   <div class="container" align="center">
  <div class="top_text">
   <p id="intro">The Best <b>Pest Control Services</b></p>
  </div>
  <div class="top_form">
                <!--some content-->
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
```

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-size: cover` (or `background-size: 100% 100%`) can be used on body or another element to have the background image or color cover the whole element.

[MDN example](http://whereswalden.com/files/mozilla/background-size/page-cover.html)

and if you don't want the size of elements to change when you change the window size, don't use % sizes, but fixed units sizes.

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML

```
html { 
      background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This is for the whole page, what if I want it for a particular element. Say for class 'container' in the above code?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container { 
  padding: 20px 70px;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.top {
  background-color: #6495ed;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div.top_text {
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 35px;
  float :left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 550px;
}
```